# MacBook Pro 2018 Random Restart > Previous shutdown cause: -20

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, mojave, restart

I have MacBook Pro 2018 (Mojave 10.14.1) just brought it 3 weeks ago,

now i have random restart when i use it.

i only browse internet, play spotify but suddenly the screen goes black and it restarted.

it's very annoying, knowing im not use it for heavy task.

im checking with

```
log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Previous shutdown cause"' --last 24h
```

Result :

```
2018-12-02 21:23:31.803844+0700 0xb6       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: -20
2018-12-03 04:49:02.918465+0700 0x266d3    Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2018-12-03 06:49:58.180398+0700 0x26d21    Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2018-12-03 07:30:06.076770+0700 0x2721c    Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2018-12-03 09:50:55.501253+0700 0xb6       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: -20
```

This is my EtreCheck result :

```
EtreCheck version: 5.0.3 (5018)
Report generated: 2018-12-03 09:57:27
Download EtreCheck from https://etrecheck.com
Runtime: 1:47
Performance: Excellent
Sandbox: Enabled
Full drive access: Disabled

Problem: Computer is restarting

Major Issues:
Anything that appears on this list needs immediate attention.

No Time Machine backup - Time Machine backup not found.

Minor Issues:
These issues do not need immediate attention but they may indicate future problems.

Clean up - There are orphan files that could be removed.
Unsigned files - There are unsigned software files installed. They appear to be legitimate but should be reviewed.
Heavy I/O usage - Your system is under heavy I/O use. This will reduce your performance.
32-bit Apps - This machine has 32-bits apps that may have problems in the future.
Abnormal shutdown - Your machine shut down abnormally.
Limited drive access - More information may be available with Full Drive Access.

Hardware Information:
MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018)
MacBook Pro Model: MacBookPro15,2
1 2,3 GHz Intel Core i5 (i5-8259U) CPU: 4-core
8 GB RAM - Not upgradeable
BANK 0/ChannelA-DIMM0 - 4 GB LPDDR3 2133 ok
BANK 2/ChannelB-DIMM0 - 4 GB LPDDR3 2133 ok
Battery: Health = Normal - Cycle count = 10

Video Information:
Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655 - VRAM: 1536 MB
Color LCD 2880 x 1800

Drives:
disk0 - APPLE SSD AP0256M 251.00 GB (Solid State - TRIM: Yes)
Internal PCI-Express 8.0 GT/s x4 NVM Express
disk0s1 - EFI [EFI] 315 MB
disk0s2 [APFS Container] 250.69 GB
disk1 [APFS Virtual drive] 250.69 GB (Shared by 4 volumes)
disk1s1 - Macintosh HD (APFS) (Shared - 96.03 GB used)
disk1s2 - Preboot (APFS) [APFS Preboot] (Shared)
disk1s3 - Recovery (APFS) [Recovery] (Shared)
disk1s4 - VM (APFS) [APFS VM] (Shared - 2.15 GB used)

Mounted Volumes:
disk1s1 - Macintosh HD 250.69 GB (151.81 GB free)
APFS
Mount point: /
Encrypted

disk1s4 - VM [APFS VM] (Shared - 2.15 GB used)
APFS
Mount point: /private/var/vm
Encrypted

Network:
Interface en0: Wi-Fi
802.11 a/b/g/n/ac
Interface en6: Bluetooth PAN
Interface bridge0: Thunderbolt Bridge

System Software:
macOS Mojave 10.14.1 (18B75)
Time since boot: Less than an hour

Security:
System  Status
Gatekeeper  Enabled
System Integrity Protection Enabled

Unsigned Files:
Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist
Executable: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Helper-Tool
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: /Library/LaunchAgents/com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist
Executable: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Java Updater.app/Contents/MacOS/Java Updater -bgcheck
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist
Executable: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Helper-Tool
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist
Executable: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Java Updater.app/Contents/MacOS/Java Updater -bgcheck
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.intel.haxm.plist
Executable: /Library/Extensions/intelhaxm.kext/Contents/Resources/haxm_start.sh
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist
Executable: /usr/local/Cellar/watchman/4.9.0_2/libexec/bin/watchman --foreground --logfile --log-level --sockname --statefile --pidfile
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK

32-bit Applications:
2 32-bit apps

Kernel Extensions:
/Library/Extensions
intelhaxm.kext (Intel Corporation Apps, 7.3.2 - SDK 10.9)

System Launch Agents:
[Not Loaded]    16 Apple tasks
[Loaded]    175 Apple tasks
[Running]   108 Apple tasks

System Launch Daemons:
[Not Loaded]    36 Apple tasks
[Loaded]    187 Apple tasks
[Running]   113 Apple tasks

Launch Agents:
[Not Loaded]    com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist (? 4e1c2192 - installed 2018-11-22)
[Running]   com.bjango.istatmenus.agent.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2018-11-23)
[Running]   com.bjango.istatmenus.status.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2018-11-23)
[Running]   com.teamviewer.teamviewer_desktop.plist (TeamViewer GmbH - installed 2018-12-03)
[Running]   com.teamviewer.teamviewer.plist (TeamViewer GmbH - installed 2018-12-03)

Launch Daemons:
[Running]   com.bjango.istatmenus.daemon.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2018-11-23)
[Running]   com.teamviewer.teamviewer_service.plist (TeamViewer GmbH - installed 2018-12-03)
[Loaded]    com.teamviewer.Helper.plist (TeamViewer GmbH - installed 2018-11-14)
[Not Loaded]    com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist (? e3fefdd2 - installed 2018-11-22)
[Loaded]    com.bjango.istatmenus.installerhelper.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2018-11-21)
[Running]   com.bjango.istatmenus.fans.plist (? 9a713d46 - installed 2018-11-23)
[Loaded]    com.intel.haxm.plist (? 42f307e7 - installed 2018-09-18)

User Launch Agents:
[Other] com.lminhtm.tempmonitor.helper.plist (? 0 - installed 2018-11-21)
[Loaded]    com.google.keystone.agent.plist (Google, Inc. - installed 2018-11-21)
[Running]   com.github.facebook.watchman.plist (? 0 - installed 2018-11-21)
[Other] com.lminhtm.tempmonitor.menu.plist (? 0 - installed 2018-11-21)

User Login Items:
Macs Fan Control.app (Ilya Parniuk - installed 2018-11-21)
(/Applications/Macs Fan Control.app)
StartUpHelper (Spotify - installed 2018-11-30)
(/Applications/Spotify.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/StartUpHelper.app)

Internet Plug-ins:
QuickTime Plugin: 7.7.3 (installed 2018-10-24)
JavaAppletPlugin: Java 8 Update 191 build 12 (installed 2018-11-22)

Safari Extensions:
Ghostery Lite Content Blocker - App Store (installed 2018-10-20)
Ghostery Lite UI - App Store (installed 2018-10-20)

3rd Party Preference Panes:
Java (installed 2018-10-06)

Time Machine:
Time Machine Not Configured!

Performance:
System Load: 4.55 (1 min ago) 16.33 (5 min ago) 9.82 (15 min ago)
Nominal I/O speed: 26.43 MB/s
File system: 19.06 seconds
Write speed: 1212 MB/s
Read speed: 3098 MB/s

CPU Usage:
Type    Overall Individual cores
System  5 % 12 %    2 % 9 % 1 % 8 % 1 % 6 % 1 %
User    6 % 16 %    1 % 14 %    1 % 11 %    1 % 8 % 1 %
Idle    89 %    72 %    98 %    77 %    98 %    81 %    98 %    86 %    98 %

Top Processes by CPU:
Process (count) Source  CPU Location
Other processes ?   50.34 % 
com.apple.WebKit.WebContent (3) Apple   13.95 % 
com.apple.WebKit.Networking (2) Apple   8.36 %  
Safari  Apple   7.26 %  
EtreCheck   App Store   6.83 %  

Top Processes by Memory:
Process (count) Source  RAM usage   Location
EtreCheck   App Store   530 MB  
Finder  Apple   128 MB  
Safari  Apple   85 MB   
Spotify Spotify 74 MB   
WhatsApp    App Store   69 MB   

Top Processes by Network Use:
Process Source  Input   Output  Location
corespeechd Apple   2 KB    3 MB    
Spotify Spotify 809 KB  142 KB  
WhatsApp    App Store   513 KB  7 KB    
com.apple.WebKit.Networking Apple   327 KB  15 KB   
biometrickitd   Apple   66 KB   98 KB   

Virtual Memory Information:
Available RAM   1.69 GB
Free RAM    179 MB
Used RAM    6.31 GB
Cached files    1.51 GB
Swap Used   407 MB

Software Installs (past 30 days):
Name    Version Install Date
Disk Speed Test 3.2 2018-11-21
Intel(R) Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager     2018-11-21
Numbers 5.0 2018-11-21
Pages   7.0 2018-11-21
Keynote 8.0 2018-11-21
Safari  12.0.1  2018-11-21
iTunes  12.8    2018-11-21
WhatsApp    0.3.1242    2018-11-21
LINE    5.11.2  2018-11-21
Security Update 2018-002    10.13.6 2018-11-21
GhosteryLite    1.0.0   2018-11-21
Gatekeeper Configuration Data   156 2018-11-21
Transmit    5.2.1   2018-11-21
SHAREit 0.9.0   2018-11-21
JDK 8 Update 191        2018-11-22
TeamViewer  14.0.13880  2018-11-27
Trello  2.10.8  2018-11-27
Movie Video Editor MovieMator   2.4.4   2018-11-27
EtreCheck   5.0.3   2018-11-29
Unity   2018.2.17f1 2018-11-30
Mono Framework      2018-11-30
Unity Documentation 2018.2.17f1 2018-11-30
AndroidPlayer   2018.2.17f1 2018-11-30
iOSSupport  2018.2.17f1 2018-11-30
The Unarchiver  4.0.0   2018-11-30
Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.1.302 (x64)   2.1.302 2018-11-30
Be Focused  1.7.5   2018-12-01

Clean up:
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.lminhtm.tempmonitor.helper.plist
/private/var/folders/7q/sm127g612mz1fh2pylgq_6680000gn/T/AppTranslocation/6FD62EBD-11A0-4599-B688-796A5E8C370D/d/Temp Monitor.app/Contents/Components/Temp Monitor Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Temp Monitor Helper
Executable not found
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.lminhtm.tempmonitor.menu.plist
/private/var/folders/7q/sm127g612mz1fh2pylgq_6680000gn/T/AppTranslocation/6FD62EBD-11A0-4599-B688-796A5E8C370D/d/Temp Monitor.app/Contents/Components/Temp Monitor Menu.app/Contents/MacOS/Temp Monitor Menu
Executable not found

Diagnostics Information (past 7 days):
2018-12-03 09:50:55 Last Shutdown Cause: -20 - Unknown

Directory /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports is not accessible without Full Drive Access.

End of report
```

I searched on the internet about this -20 shutdown code, but i can't find the answer.

Is it a new kind of shutdown code from Mojave?

Any opinion and solution will be appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**

tried calling :

```
sudo log show --start "2018-12-2 10:45:17" --end "2018-12-3 23:45:47" --info --debug --signpost | grep -i Restart
```

and tried matching the log with the shutdown log time, and here's what i found :

```
2018-12-03 09:47:10.007046+0700 0x2bf      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSmartBatteryManager) Restarting poll type 4
2018-12-03 09:48:10.019603+0700 0x2bf      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSmartBatteryManager) Restarting poll type 4
2018-12-03 09:50:55.499364+0700 0xca       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSmartBatteryManager) Restarting poll type 1
2018-12-03 09:50:55.522901+0700 0x7a       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSmartBatteryManager) AppleSmartBattery::pollBatteryState already polling (1 <= 1). Restarting poll
2018-12-03 09:50:55.527298+0700 0x7a       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSmartBatteryManager) Restarting poll type 1
2018-12-03 09:50:58.206753+0700 0x2c1      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSmartBatteryManager) Restarting poll type 1
2018-12-03 09:50:58.345994+0700 0x2c1      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSmartBatteryManager) Restarting poll type 1
2018-12-03 09:50:58.387372+0700 0x44d      Default     0x0                  161    0    contextstored: (KnowledgeMonitor) [com.apple.coreduet.context:] Restart preventer: <private>
2018-12-03 09:50:58.849621+0700 0x2ea      Default     0x0                  90     8    dasd: (DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon) [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:default] Using restart times of <private>
2018-12-03 09:51:04.835339+0700 0x45b      Default     0x0                  90     8    dasd: (DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon) [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:lifecycle] Attempting to suspend based on triggers: (     "com.apple.duetactivityscheduler.restartpolicy.assertionsheld" )
2018-12-03 09:51:07.008186+0700 0x2d7      Default     0x0                  94     0    loginwindow: (BezelServices) [com.apple.BezelServices:loginwindow] timer restarted. _keyDimTime 300 idleTime 0.520
2018-12-03 09:51:07.008465+0700 0x2d7      Default     0x0                  94     5    loginwindow: [com.apple.loginwindow.logging:Standard] -[HardwareStartupManager needsHardwareUpdateCheck] | checking EOS
2018-12-03 09:51:07.010448+0700 0x2d7      Default     0x0                  94     5    loginwindow: [com.apple.loginwindow.logging:Standard] -[HardwareStartupManager needsHardwareUpdateCheck] | returning: 0
2018-12-03 09:51:07.192429+0700 0x2d7      Default     0x0                  94     0    loginwindow: (BezelServices) [com.apple.BezelServices:loginwindow] timer restarted. _keyDimTime 300 idleTime 0.704
2018-12-03 09:51:07.501926+0700 0x3f0      Default     0x0                  90     8    dasd: (DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon) [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:lifecycle] Attempting to suspend based on triggers: (     "com.apple.duetactivityscheduler.restartpolicy.assertionsheld" )
2018-12-03 09:51:07.501957+0700 0x3f0      Default     0x0                  90     8    dasd: (DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon) [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:default] Ignoring trigger com.apple.duetactivityscheduler.restartpolicy.assertionsheld because conditions are deteriorating
2018-12-03 09:51:09.788532+0700 0x2d7      Default     0x0                  94     5    loginwindow: [com.apple.loginwindow.logging:Standard] -[ScreenSaverDaemon restartForUser:] | restartForUser, userName == nil:0
2018-12-03 09:51:09.791831+0700 0x2d7      Default     0x0                  94     5    loginwindow: [com.apple.loginwindow.logging:Standard] -[ScreenSaverDaemon restartForUser:] | no screen saver running, call _handleIdleTimer
2018-12-03 09:51:09.820568+0700 0x2d7      Default     0x0                  94     5    loginwindow: [com.apple.loginwindow.logging:TAL] -[PersistentAppsSupport previousStartupWasAPanicOrHardRestart] | returning:0
2018-12-03 09:51:09.820572+0700 0x2d7      Default     0x0                  94     5    loginwindow: [com.apple.loginwindow.logging:TAL] -[PersistentAppsSupport checkTALLoginOptions] |      firstLoginAfterPanic:0, firstLoginAfterHardRestart:0, lastTALLogoutPrefSetting:1, previousStartupWasPanicOrHardReset:0, skipTALWarningPrefIsSet:0
2018-12-03 09:51:12.021717+0700 0xbf3      Default     0x0                  280    0    secd: [com.apple.securityd:ckksoutgoing-Engram] End of operation group: <CKOperationGroup: 0x7fb153d26bb0; configs=, operationGroupID=1A9266C4DD0EBFB4, recv-size=Kilobytes, full-name=restart-setup, defaultConfiguration=<CKOperationConfiguration: 0x7fb153d28020>, send-size=Kilobytes>
```

Comment: suggest you try `sudo log show --start "2018-10-23 23:45:17" --end "2018-10-24 23:45:47" --info --debug --signpost | grep -i Restart` adjust date/time to your situation.

Comment: i did, do you have any ideas what the log says? @Buscar웃

Comment: It does not show anything unusual, lets see if someone is sending Sigkill `sudo log show --start start "2018-12-2 10:45:17" --end "2018-12-3 23:45:47 --info --debug --signpost | grep -i Sigkill`

Comment: I'm having the same problem with my iMac Pro. According to last, I've had about 19 crashes since Sep 25th. According to logs, the last three reboots have been due to cause -20. Did you ever find out what it is?

Comment: -20 error code here as well. Super frequent shutdowns. I have even stopped receiving "Your computer was shutdown due to an error" now. It just reboots.

Answer (score 2):

I used to get shutdown cause -20. Then I uninstalled McAfee VirusScan. I still don't know what cause -20 refers to but it hasn't happened since I uninstalled McAfee VirusScan. If you have any software that installs a kernel extension as many virus scanners do, try uninstalling that software or booting in safe mode (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I would second this hunch / correlation / report. Might you have been able to recall or save if you got any panic.log files that were dumped at the time of a -20 cause in the logs?

Comment: I think by now all the relevant logs have rolled off, unfortunately. But it was a very strong correlation, literally the only software I removed was McAfee.

Answer (score 1):

I to experience the same random restart problem.  I agree is seems like some app requested a system restart with no error associated with it.  It seemed to be only associated with my account, the guest account did not exhibit the same problem but deleting my old account and starting a new one did not fix it.  The only thing that worked for me was to erase the disk and reinstall the OS, like the previous person.

BTW, I installed iStat Menu after I started experiencing the problem so I don't think it was that app.

Before I found this post, a work around for this that I used when I had to leave the computer working on something unattended was to open an editor and make a change to a file but don't save it.  The OS will stop the restart until the editor can be shut down.  I used emacs but I'm sure any non-cloud based editing SW would work.

Comment: Well i think i got the problem again, it's restarting again for the past 2 weeks, 
right now im downgrading my os into high sierra, if the problem still persist, i think im going to apple service center for a service claim...